# How do I use Telegram instead of email for account confirmation in a Next.js app?

Tags: email, next.js, gmail, telegram, amazon-ses

I have a Next.js app where new users register and confirm their email addresses. After the person gives their information, a confirmation email is sent to the user. They click a discrete link that triggers a GET request with a unique id passed in through a URL parameter. When this GET request is triggered the user is changed from unverified to verified in my database. Is there any way to do this same verification process through Telegram?

I think there's more security with Telegram accounts than email addresses. I might be very wrong in this assumption. I am speaking from my experience of making multiple email addresses. There are a lot of services that allow you to make an email address with very little information. Most email services just require a separate email address. Services like Protonmail, Gmail, etc... only require a separate email address. You only need to find 1 service that doesn't require anything and you're in lol.

To create a Telegram account, I think you need to provide a phone number. My experience with phone numbers is that it's very hard to get more than 1. I know there are shared number services that people use to register for websites and apps in order to remain anonymous, but most of the time they don't work. The numbers take a long time to receive messages (most services only allow for a minute of wait time) and they have usually already been used for someone else's account on the service you seek to create. Therefore your verification attempt won't work.

This is some of my code that I use to send a verification email in a next.js `/api` route:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' });

export default async function handler(  

  // more code here  

  // Set up the email transport using Amazon SES
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      SES: ses,
    })

    // Set up the email options
    const mailOptions = {
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM, // Your email address
      to: createContact.email, // Newly created contact's email
      subject: 'Confirmation Email',
      text: `Hello ${createContact.name},\n\nClick this link to confirm your email address: ${process.env.ROOT_DOMAIN}/confirm?id=${createContact.confirm_key}\n\n`,
    } as MailOptions

    // Send the email
    try {
      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
      console.log('Email sent to', createContact.email)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error)
      return res.status(500).json({ subjectName: 'None', emailAddrs: 'None', is_valid: false })
    }  

  // more code  
}
```